# Getting value from Collection in Meteor

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor, collections

I'm trying to get the value from a collection which looks a little confusing for me.

Collection looks like this

```
{
"_id" : "bqaGRGotKzYiA6mZv",
"0" : {
    "MessageId" : "8B25CEB0-9EC6-48F7-9826-0AC813E903F8",
    "Requested" : ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:40.173Z")        
},
"1" : {
    "MessageId" : "B02935F0-8492-4858-B8C1-0BCEA9BCC80B",
    "Requested" : ISODate("2015-10-08T16:59:45.503Z")
},
"2" : {
    "MessageId" : "F766B029-BB81-4E6C-90B5-71B51B8F77FA",
    "Requested" : ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:22.956Z")
},
"3" : {
    "MessageId" : "D88D87EE-CD25-4624-8265-8D66D8D9163A",
    "Requested" : ISODate("2015-10-08T17:24:20.906Z")
    }
}
```

Now I want to display to client a table with "Requested" values in 1 column 
is there any other way than pointing each number manually?

This is the helper

```
 myHelper: function(){
      return Tasks.find();
    }
```

and the code below will print the "ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:40.173Z")"

```
{{#each myHelper}}
  {{[0].Requested}}
{{/each}}
```

But I want some automatic action because I don't know how many numbers will be in collection.

Comment: This really should use a nested array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create global helper that will convert each object from your collection to an array.

```
Template.registerHelper("convertToArray", function(){
    var self = this; //this points to single object from collection.
    var array = [];
    var keys = _.without(Object.keys(this), "_id");
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        array.push(self[key]);
    }) 
    return array;
});
```

Optionally you can sort keys before looping through it.

Then use it like this:

```
{{#each myHelper}}
    {{#each convertToArray}}
      {{Requested}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks Man!! 
you saved my life :D

Answer (score 1):

I may not tell what you expect or need to accomplish your goal, but the collection organization approach you have taken feels a bit odd to me. So I'll post my answer, too.

If you had a collection item like this

```
{
    "_id": "bqaGRGotKzYiA6mZv",
    "messages": [{
        "MessageId": "8B25CEB0-9EC6-48F7-9826-0AC813E903F8",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:40.173Z")
    }, {
        "MessageId": "B02935F0-8492-4858-B8C1-0BCEA9BCC80B",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T16:59:45.503Z")
    }, {
        "MessageId": "F766B029-BB81-4E6C-90B5-71B51B8F77FA",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:22.956Z")
    }, {
        "MessageId": "D88D87EE-CD25-4624-8265-8D66D8D9163A",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T17:24:20.906Z")
    }]
}
```

or, even if you need to store items' IDs explicitly, like this:

```
{
    "_id": "bqaGRGotKzYiA6mZv",
    "messages": [{
        "id": 0,
        "MessageId": "8B25CEB0-9EC6-48F7-9826-0AC813E903F8",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:40.173Z")
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "MessageId": "B02935F0-8492-4858-B8C1-0BCEA9BCC80B",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T16:59:45.503Z")
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "MessageId": "F766B029-BB81-4E6C-90B5-71B51B8F77FA",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T16:47:22.956Z")
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "MessageId": "D88D87EE-CD25-4624-8265-8D66D8D9163A",
        "Requested": ISODate("2015-10-08T17:24:20.906Z")
    }]
}
```

then you would be able to provide the data from helper to the template like this:

```
myHelper: function(_id) {
    return Tasks.find({
        _id: _id
    });
}
```

and use it like this:

```
{{#each myHelper}}
    {{#each message}}
        {{MessageId}}
        {{Requested}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

You could also add `messages` items to a collection item like this:

```
var theMessage = {
    "MessageId": "whatever",
    "Requested": "whenever"
}

Tasks.update({
    _id: _id
}, {
    $push: {
        messages: theMessage
    }
});
```